# Evaluating limits without the usage of graph

Tags: limits

> $\lim_{x \to 1} {\frac{x^3-1}{x^2-1}}$

Is there a way to evaluate this limit when $x$ Approaches 1 without using a graph? From graph, its easy to see, that as its $\frac{3}{2}$ but how do we simplify and break the fraction down because if I substitute $x=1$ to the expression I get $\frac{0}{0}$

Comment: $x^{2}-1=(x-1)(x+1)$ and $x^{3}-1=(x-1)(x^{2}+x+1)$.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use L'Hôpital's rule and take the derivative of the top and bottom independently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several tricks you can use. For cases where you get $\frac00$ you can use [L'Hospital's rule](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/LHospitalsRule.aspx) to get

$$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{x^3-1}{x^2-1} = \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{3x^2}{2x} = \frac32$$

In addition, as shown by @geetha290krm, you can sometimes factor the numerator and denominator to get something that isn't indeterminate.